# Should I finish FFXIII before beginning FFXIII-2?

Tags: final-fantasy-13, final-fantasy-13-2

I got Final Fantasy XIII when it came out, and played up to the beginning of Chapter 8 before real life pulled me away.

Being the impulsive spendaholic that I am, I have now purchased Final Fantasy XIII-2. My question is, should I go back to and finish the original before beginning on the sequel? Am I to expect major spoilers in XIII-2 that could seriously impact my enjoyment if/when I eventually return to XIII?

Comment: If you don't want to actually play XIII all the way through (or if you want to start at Chapter 8 of XIII and get a recap of what happened before it) XIII-2 does have a Beginner's Primer that goes over 13 chapters from XIII.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you don't want the ending of *Final Fantasy XIII* to be completely and irrevocably spoiled, do not play *Final Fantasy XIII-2* until you complete it: don't look at it, read reviews, play the demo, or anything.

*Final Fantasy XIII-2* is a direct sequel to *Final Fantasy XIII*, and its entire plot hinges on the events at the ending of *Final Fantasy XIII*. That ending will be spoiled within 15 minutes of starting *Final Fantasy XIII-2*.

Comment: And not only that, but the ending of FFXIII probably has a few surprises for you, so we're talking major spoilers.  It's not just "Yay, the good guys win!"

Comment: ...also, I might add "Don't even read the back of the box!" although it may be a bit late for that.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend it. Broadly speaking, Chapter 8 is where the last 2 protagonists stop running and accept their fate as l'Cie. What follows next is a revelation to their Focus, followed by their reaction to it. Given that FF XIII-2 takes place on Pulse, you may want to complete the story.

Answer (score 1):

Something everyone has missed in their answers is the fact that you can do a sort of "what happened in XIII?" replay thing where it shows you the basic story outline of FFXIII.

If your not interested in actually finishing XIII then you can just start XIII-2 and watch through this instead.

I'd personally go for finishing the first one, however if you really can't be bothered then this is a simply way to carry on yet know whats happening with the storyline.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend it. Aside from the plot reasons posters outlined above, XIII-2 doesn't do much to help you master the paradigm system its combat hinges upon. Finishing XIII will make you much more comfortable with the fights in this game.